# Make parent directives available to content rendered via ngTemplateOutlet in Angular

Tags: angular

Consider I have a form with multiple sections that are rendered using the [ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet).

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <ng-container *ngIf="true; then fooSection"></ng-container>
</form>

<ng-template #fooSection>
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isEulaAccepted">
<ng-template>
```

The problem is that `formControlName` can't access the parent `formGroup` directive.

Is it possible to make it work this way?

Comment: Is the `FormsModule` imported in both modules (the module declaring the component with the `ngTemplateOutlet` + the module declaring the component with the `<ng-template>`)? If not, the `formControlName` will be nothing more than an html attribute, no directive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that the most simple solution is to use the `formGroup` directive multiple times:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <ng-container *ngIf="true; then fooSection"></ng-container>
</form>

<ng-template #fooSection>
  <ng-container [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isEulaAccepted">
  </ng-container>
<ng-template>
```

Looks like Angular is OK with that. However, other answers is useful too when it comes to a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, I mean when you want to using `formControlName`, then you should have to put it inside `[formGroup]="formGroup"` section.

For an example, you only can do something like this code below:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ng-container *ngIf="true; then fooSection"></ng-container>

  <ng-template #fooSection>
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isEulaAccepted">
  <ng-template>
</form>
```

**Update:** Or you can do this, if you want to put outside `[formGroup]` section.

In your typescript, you can do add this:

```js
public get isEulaAccepted(): FormControl {
  return this.formGroup.get('isEulaAccepted') as FormControl;
}
```

Or if you only have one `formControl`, so you should not have to using `formGroup`, just using `formControl` like this:

```js
public isEulaAccepted: FormControl = new FormControl(null);
```

And, in your html, you can use this one:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="true; then fooSection"></ng-container>

<ng-template #fooSection>
  <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="isEulaAccepted" />
  <ng-template></ng-template
></ng-template>
```

Now, it will working fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: `FormControlName` directive injects the `ControlContainer` with `@Host()` parameter decorator, so if it is not found in the parent, it throws an error. But you can provide the `ControlContainer` for it in another way.

- create a wrapper component in the same file as the main component such this

```
let group;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  @ViewChild(FormGroupDirective, { static: true }) formGroup: FormGroupDirective 

  form = new FormGroup({
    isEulaAccepted: new FormControl(),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    group = this.formGroup;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useFactory: (app: WrapperComponent) => {
        return group;
      },
      deps: [forwardRef(() => WrapperComponent)],
    },
  ],
})
export class WrapperComponent {}
```

and use the `WrapperComponent` in template such this

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ng-template
    *ngTemplateOutlet="fooSection;"
  ></ng-template>
</form>

<ng-template #fooSection>
  <wrapper>
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isEulaAccepted" />
  </wrapper>
</ng-template>

{{ formGroup.value | json }}
```

[This is the final solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5yfgtx?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: That's pretty clever, however, I've found that its easier to just use the `formGroup` directive multiple times - looks like Angular is OK with that :)